# How do I get the name of a Ruby class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

How can I get the class name from an ActiveRecord object?

I have:

```
result = User.find(1)
```

I tried:

```
result.class
# => User(id: integer, name: string ...)
result.to_s
# => #<User:0x3d07cdc>"
```

I need only the class name, in a string (`User` in this case). Is there a method for that?

I know this is pretty basic, but I searched both Rails' and Ruby's docs, and I couldn't find it.

Comment: @Oliver N.: With normal Ruby objects, `Object#class.inspect` gives the same as `Object#class.name`, whereas this isn't the case with ActiveRecord objects.

Answer (score 817, accepted):

You want to call [.name](https://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M001699) on the object's class:

```
result.class.name
```

Comment: When I do this I get the Module names before it, so "Module::SubModule::Class", is there a way of getting just "Class"

Comment: @Abe: `result.class.name.split('::').last`

Comment: @Abe: even cleaner (ActiveSupport): `result.class.name.demodulize`

Comment: For the newcomers out there, you can also obtain the class name as a string by using the class like this: `User.name`. `User.to_s` also seems to work.

Comment: The demodulize method comes from here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/demodulize

(You need to load the ActiveSupport string inflections to be able to use if, if you are not a Rails project.)

Comment: How do you do when the class hides its name ? I wanted to get the full namespace + class of a proxy object, but its name was overriden with `[Proxy] Foo` ?
EDIT : It's possible to show the name by triggering an error on the class and the real class name will be printed in the debug, but well..

Answer (score 139):

Here's the correct answer, extracted from comments by Daniel Rikowski and pseidemann.  I'm tired of having to weed through comments to find the right answer...

If you use Rails (ActiveSupport):

```
result.class.name.demodulize
```

If you use POR (plain-ol-Ruby):

```
result.class.name.split('::').last
```

Comment: An answer that is comparing a solution to others and claims to better, should also explain why.

Comment: well, technically, my comment answered more than what was originally asked ;)

Answer (score 38):

Both `result.class.to_s` and `result.class.name` work.

Comment: But conceptually, #name returns the name, #to_s returns a string representation, which just happens to be identical to the name. I'd stick to using #name, just out of anal-retentiveness.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to get a class name from inside a class method, `class.name` or `self.class.name` won't work.  These will just output `Class`, since the class of a class is `Class`.  Instead, you can just use `name`:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
    def self.say_name
      puts "I'm a #{name}!"
    end
  end
end

Foo::Bar.say_name
```

output:

```
I'm a Foo::Bar!
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, that feels counterintuitive, but checks out.  It's strange because it feels  easy and common to override `name`, especially in an ActiveRecord model; many models will have a `name` attribute. If that were the case, how would we get the class name?

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby, you'd use the `object.class.name` method as follows.

```rb
module Bank
  class Account
  end
end

irb(main):005:0> account = Bank::Account.new
=> #<Bank::Account:0x0000000106115b00>
irb(main):006:0> account.class.name
=> "Bank::Account"
irb(main):008:0> account.class.name.split("::").last
=> "Account"
```

In Rails, as others mentioned, you can use the [`demodulize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-demodulize) method on a string, which is added by Active Support. It removes the module part from the constant expression in the string.

```bash
irb(main):014:0> account.class.name.demodulize
=> "Account"
```

Internally, this method calls the [`demodulize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-demodulize) class method on the `ActiveSupport::Inflector` class, passing itself as the argument.

```rb
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb, line 166
def demodulize
  ActiveSupport::Inflector.demodulize(self)
end
```

The `Inflector.demodulize` function does the same thing.

```rb
demodulize('ActiveSupport::Inflector::Inflections') # => "Inflections"
demodulize('Inflections')                           # => "Inflections"
demodulize('::Inflections')                         # => "Inflections"
demodulize('')                                      # => ""
```

However, its internal implementation is different than the simple version above.

```rb
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb, line 228
def demodulize(path)
  path = path.to_s
  if i = path.rindex("::")
    path[(i + 2)..-1]
  else
    path
  end
end
```

After converting the path argument to a string, it gets the index of the last occurrence of `::` using Ruby's [`rindex`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/String.html#method-i-rindex) function. If it exists, then it returns the remaining substring. Otherwise, it returns the original string. The `array[n..-1]` expression returns the substring from `n` to the last character in the string.

Now I haven't done any benchmark studies to find why Rails uses this alternative approach using `rindex` (please comment if you know why), but as a code readability enthusiast, I like the first one using the `split` and `last` functions.

*Source: [How to Get an Object's Class Name in Rails](https://www.akshaykhot.com/how-to-get-objects-class-name-in-ruby-rails/)*

Answer (score 2):

In my case when I use something like `result.class.name` I got something like `Module1::class_name`. But if we only want `class_name`, use

`result.class.table_name.singularize`