# Rails: Determine Which Model an Object is Derived From

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array that contains objects from two models:

```
  @search_results = User.find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query]}%"])
  @search_results += Book.find(:all, :conditions => ['title LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query]}%"])
```

I then tried to parse them out like so:

```
<% @search_results.each do |result| %>
  <% if result.title %>
    <%= link_to result.title, result %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to result.name, result %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I had hoped that the if statement would parse books (which have a title) from users (which do not). Unfortunately, the if statement itself throws the error "Undefined method `title' for #". What else can I do to determine the model an object belongs to?

PS. I want to keep both models in the same array so I can rank the results by a shared attribute, page_views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
result.class.name
```

Reference : [How do I get the name of a Ruby class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826210/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-a-ruby-class)