# Get class name from a class nested in a module in ruby

Tags: ruby

If I give you:

```
module Something
  module SomethingElse
    class Foo
    end
  end
end
```

How do you get the class name of "Foo"? In the console, I have something similar to the example, but when I do `.name` on it it doesn't print out what I expect.

This is whats in my console:

```
pry(main)> AisisWriter::Controllers::CommentsManagement::CommentsHandler.name
=> "AisisWriter::Controllers::CommentsManagement::CommentsHandler"
```

What I expect is just "CommentsHandler"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24832287/438992

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
AisisWriter::Controllers::CommentsManagement::CommentsHandler.name.split('::').last || ''
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have ActiveSupport included, try `demodulize` method

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html

Comment: Note that you must call `:demodulize` on the string, not the class. For instance:  `A::B::C.name.demodulize` (return string via `:name`, then call `:demodulize`)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple.

```
AisisWriter::Controllers::CommentsManagement::CommentsHandler.name.split(':').last
```

Comment: It's better to split on "::". End result is the same, but reveals intention better.

Comment: why, if the single colon doesn't appear anywhere else in the name?

Comment: Result of splitting on "::" can be used for a couple of other tasks. Result of splitting on ":" is useless (except for this case) because of the empty strings in it.

Comment: yes, but I'm not initializing this array or using it for anything else.

Comment: Anyhow, the separator here is "::", not ":". Benefit of not using full separator is unclear to me.