# How to get the class name from an instance variable in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

If I have `@commentable`, which could either be a Post or Article, can I extract the model name from the instance variable?

Comment: You may always use is_a? to test for a certain type.

Comment: The question always is: why do you need it? If you are planning to use it for forking your flow it will be a serious architectural error (breaking Demeter law) which you will need to pay for later.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the name of a Ruby class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826210/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-a-ruby-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@commentable.class.name` to find out the variable's class name.

Comment: another way to do it is `@commentable.class.to_s.underscore`

Comment: `@commentable.class.model_name.singular` is a rails way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
@commentable.class.name
```

But here is a gotcha. If the name of a class is like this `ActiveRecord::Base` i.e. it contains a module as well, you can call `demodulize` to get only the class name.

```
@instance_variable.class.name.demodulize # when the class name contains any module.
```