# Method class_name undefined for Class object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am having an issue where class_name seems to work on something like

`User.first.class.class_name` locally but it seems to fail in production.

I am trying to figure out where class_name is defined (I am using it on something like `Admin::User.first.name.class_name` to return `"User"` since I want the demodulized class name.) Why would it not work on production?

Where can I see what module class_name is a part of?

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24832287/908842 - demodularized class name

Comment: undefined method class_name for #<Class::4539q5834905834> (some class object)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`class_name` method is defined by yard gem. it works only development env.

or

Check which module define `class_name`

```
User.method(:class_name).source_location
```